# Opening a cash drawer using POS .NET has casting error?

Tags: c#

I am trying to open a cash drawer using POS .NET 1.14. After some research, I found some code on SO, but when trying to run the example, I get an error in Visual Studio:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.PointOfService.PosDevice' to 'Microsoft.PointOfService.CashDrawer'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The code is as follows:

```
namespace POSDrawer
{
    public class CashDrawerClass
    {
        CashDrawer myCashDrawer;
        PosExplorer explorer;

        public CashDrawerClass()
        {
            explorer = new PosExplorer();
            DeviceInfo ObjDevicesInfo = explorer.GetDevice("CashDrawer");
            myCashDrawer = explorer.CreateInstance(ObjDevicesInfo); // THIS IS WHERE ERROR OCCURS
        }

        public void OpenCashDrawer()
        {
            myCashDrawer.Open();
            myCashDrawer.Claim(1000);
            myCashDrawer.DeviceEnabled = true;
            myCashDrawer.OpenDrawer();
            myCashDrawer.DeviceEnabled = false;
            myCashDrawer.Release();
            myCashDrawer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the documentation, and CreateInstance is expecting a DeviceInfo, so I am not entirely sure why it complains?

[MSDN documentation for PosExplorer.CreateInstance()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.pointofservice.posexplorer.createinstance%28v=winembedded.11%29.aspx)

Comment: Try changing that line to : `myCashDrawer = (CashDrawer)explorer.CreateInstance(ObjDevicesInfo);`

Comment: You are right. I feel really stupid because I looked at what was passed in, instead of what was returning. Yours is the correct solution. If you post that, I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Heinze answered the same thing.  Mark his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...CreateInstance is expecting a DeviceInfo...

That's fine, but what does `CreateInstance` return?

You are assigning the return value to a field of type `CashDrawer`, so if the return value is not a `CashDrawer` (but, for example, a `PosDevice`), you need to cast it first.

Comment: Did this but my cash drawer still isn't opening... There's no errors... The code just apparently does nothing

Comment: @Ortund: Since this is a different question, I suggest that you start a new SO question on that.